# Installation fails in xam.plugin.downloadmanager due to .net problem

Tags: xamarin

Package 'Xam.Plugin.DownloadManager 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

Comment: Are you getting error on warning?

Comment: Due to warning the nuget is not full restored .So I cant able to the access the nuget